# Looping 2 specific column and doing a calculation counter, inputting into another datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a few columns and i would like to choose 2 columns both of which are dates and loop them such that each row have a calculation with both dates but do a counter with them so i can input it into another datagridview and get a report(stats) for the datas.Columns will be randomize. I am doing this in visual studio c#.

My code (wrong)

```
private void show_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int close2 = 0, closemorethan2 = 0, execption = 0;
        connection.Open();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
                    DateTime one = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Close Date"].Value.ToString());
                    DateTime two = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Required by date"].Value.ToString());
                    DateTime test = one.Date;
                    DateTime test2 = two.Date;
                    TimeSpan diff = test.Subtract(test2);
                    if (one == null || two == null)
                    {
                        execption++;
                    }
                    else if (diff.Days <= 2)
                    {
                        close2++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        closemorethan2++;
                    }                      
                }
            }
        }
        //datagridview 2 data to show stats 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt;
        DataRow dr;
        DataColumn condition;
        DataColumn number;

        dt = new DataTable();
        condition = new DataColumn("Conditions", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        number = new DataColumn("counter", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

        dt.Columns.Add(condition);
        dt.Columns.Add(number);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Conditions"] = "Close in 2 Days";
        dr["counter"] = close2;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Conditions"] = "Close after 2 Days";
        dr["counter"] = closemorethan2;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Conditions"] = "Exceptions";
        dr["counter"] = execption;       
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();           
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        connection.Close();
    }
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeG6k.png)

[ms-access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwQhG.png)
Thank you

Comment: The line… `Convert.ToDateTime(date1);` will always fail in this context… `date1 = "select [Close Date] from dataGridView1";` `date1` should be a valid date time `string`… something like "05/01/1996." I assume you may want to change the line to `Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Close Date"].Value.ToString());` Also, it appears that looping through all the columns for each row is unnecessary since you know what columns you are looking for. The current code is doing the same (redundant) work for each column in the grid.

Comment: System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' i got this error after i changed it both date time `DateTime one = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Close Date"].Value.ToString());` and `DateTime two = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Required by date"].Value.ToString());` I took out both the query at the start and the for loop for the column

Comment: It appears the date in the picture you posted is in a format of `dd/MM/yyyy` … you should change the format to `MM/dd/yyyy`… How does the grid get its data to begin with? I am betting it would be easier to change the string to a `DateTime` object before it is displayed in the grid.

Comment: The grid is getting its data from ms-access. The datatable in access have the dates in dd/mm/yyyy format too.I have put a small part of my database as a picture.

Comment: Unfortunately, you do not show “how” the data is taken from your data base and displayed to the grid. I am betting it would be easier to get the “dates” from your database in a `DateTime` format instead of a `string` to avoid the conversion when comparing dates. I am guessing you may have to do some conversion of the dates when reading from your data base, however, it “should” allow you to get a `DateTime` object for the dates, thus, avoiding the conversion all together.

Comment: Do you mean the code of how i load the data.`connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                string comparequery = "SELECT *from [For stats]";

                command.CommandText = comparequery;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt4);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt4;

                connection.Close();`

Comment: I can only guess that `dt4` has columns of a `DateTime` type for the date columns. You should check this. If they are strings, then you may want to look at how to get the values as `DateTime` objects from your database. Otherwise, you may have to loop through `dt4` to convert the `strings` to `DateTime` objects. I am betting you can get these fields as `DateTime` objects from the data base.

Comment: I have checked that both close date and required by date are date/time in access.

Comment: But what are the column types in `dt4` ? Are they `DataTime` columns and if so, then no need to covert. Simply cast the cells value to `DateTime`, however it appears unnecessary to do this with the grid, you should loop through `dt4` to create the `dt` table.

Comment: How do you check their value in datagridview?

Comment: Check `dt4`'s column types. Put a break point at the line `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt4;` and examine `dt4` column types.

Comment: It shows date time for datatype but it shows object for base type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of what I am describing. In your update and as I stated, if the “date” data coming from the data base is in a `DateTime` object, then there is no need to “convert” the date to a `string` then convert it back to a `DateTime` object since you already have the `DateTime` object.

NOTE: from your pictures it appears the `DateTime` object returned from the data base “may” be “formatting” the date to display in the “dd/MM/yyyy” format… that is why the code will fail when you try to convert the date to a `string` and then convert that `string` back to a `DateTime` object.

Example in the line of code

```
Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Close Date"].Value.ToString())
```

will FAIL since the `ToString` method "may" be returning the date in the “dd/MM/yyyy” format. To avoid this, simply do not convert the date.

Even if the `ToString` method returns a “valid” date string, it is unnecessary to convert this string to a `DateTime` object since you already have the `DateTime` object.

Lastly, it should be noted for this context, that it is better to loop through the grids `DataTable` rows and NOT the grids rows as your current code does. Reason being that when you loop through the grids rows and try to grab a cells “Date” value like… `date1 = (DateTime)row.Cells["Close Date"].Value;` will FAIL with an invalid cast. Here you WILL need to convert the `string` value to a `DateTime` value which as we already know is unnecessary. I hope that makes sense.

```
DataTable dt4;
DataTable conditionsData;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dt4 = GetOriginalTable();
  FillOriginalTable(dt4);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt4;
}

private DataTable GetOriginalTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Work Order", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Required By Date", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("Close Date", typeof(DateTime));
  return dt;
}

private DataTable GetConditionsTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Conditions", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Counterr", typeof(int));
  return dt;
}

private void FillOriginalTable(DataTable originalDT) {
  originalDT.Rows.Add("1", "150", new DateTime(2019, 09, 19), new DateTime(2019, 09, 19));
  originalDT.Rows.Add("2", "151", new DateTime(2019, 09, 19), new DateTime(2019, 09, 21));
  originalDT.Rows.Add("3", "152", new DateTime(2019, 09, 19), new DateTime(2019, 09, 22));
  originalDT.Rows.Add("4", "153", new DateTime(2019, 09, 19));
  DataRow newRow = originalDT.NewRow();
  newRow["ID"] = "5";
  newRow["Work Order"] = "154";
  newRow["Close Date"] = new DateTime(2019, 09, 19);
  originalDT.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

private void show_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int close2 = 0;
  int closemorethan2 = 0;
  int execption = 0;
  DateTime date1;
  DateTime date2;
  TimeSpan diff;
  foreach (DataRow row in dt4.Rows) {
    if (row["Required By Date"].ToString() != "" && row["Close Date"].ToString() != "") {
      date1 = (DateTime)row["Close Date"];
      date2 = (DateTime)row["Required By Date"];
      diff = date1.Subtract(date2);
      if (diff.Days <= 2) {
        close2++;
      }
      else {
        closemorethan2++;
      }
    }
    else {
      execption++;
    }
  }
  conditionsData = GetConditionsTable();
  conditionsData.Rows.Add("Close in 2 Days", close2);
  conditionsData.Rows.Add("Close after 2 Days", closemorethan2);
  conditionsData.Rows.Add("Exceptions", execption);
  dataGridView2.DataSource = conditionsData;
}
```

Comment: How do i change the FillOriginalTable to select data from database? Do i just do a query while keeping the GetOriginaltable so that the columns are set to the proper format?

Comment: Yes, change the code in the FillOriginalTable to the query you posted earlier in your comments.